# java Thread.join doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following class

```java
class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    ThreadDemo( String name) {
        threadName = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " Counter   ---   "  + i );
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sleep issue");
        }

        System.out.println("Finishing run");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sleep issue");
        }
    }

    public void start () {
        t = new Thread (this, threadName);
        t.start ();
    }
}
```

which is tested like below

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 1 ");
        ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 2 ");
        T1.start();
        T2.start();

        //Let's give some time for threads to run
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Main sleep issue");
        }

        try {
            T1.join();
            T2.join();
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }

        System.out.println("Finishing main.");
    }
}
```

Why does I always get "Finishing main" before "Finishing run" in output despite the fact I used T1.join() and T2.join() to wait for them to finish? Initially I thought it could be due to buffer delay so I added Thread.sleep(1000) at the end of run() to give some time to print "Finishing run" but it didnt't help. I guess it's due to first occurrence of Thread.sleep(1000) (when I remove it, it work's fine) but have no idea why.

Comment: Your `ThreadDemo` class extends Thread; do not define your own `start` method but use the supemethod that comes with the class.

Comment: "when I remove it, it work's fine" no, it the thread just happens to execute quicker than the main thread, because of the `Thread.sleep(10)` there. This is mere fluke.

Comment: `extends Thread` is your first problem. You should prefer to `implement Runnable` when describing task, and later pass that task to worker (thread) which should handle it.

Comment: @Pshemo or not pass it to a thread at all, but rather pass it to an `ExecutorService` or similar, which manages threads for you.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of this:

```
public void start () {
    t = new Thread (this, threadName);
    t.start ();
}
```

So your `ThreadDemo` instance is never actually started as a thread: the thread that is printing the `Finishing run` message is the one created in that method. There is no link between that thread and the `ThreadDemo`.

Remove the `start()` method.

Comment: yes, and think twice before overriding standard method (here - method "start()").